# Most efficient way to check if the value of a web-scraped variable has changed (Python, BeautifulSoup)?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm looking to scrape the text from a website's tags, get all of that text initially, and then ONLY after that, be notified when any of the tags' text has changed. Is this infinite loop--with the initial null variable declaration--the most efficient way to implement it? It looks very clunky.

Many thanks for any help you can provide!

```
# Send an email with text from multiple HTML tags, then after that, ONLY send email
# when any of the tags' text has changed.

tagsOfInterest = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] # Any tag in this list could change each scrape.



originalTags = None

while True:
    if originalTags is None:
        originalTags = []
        for tag in tagsOfInterest:
             originalTags.append(tag)
             # Email originalTags to myself
        # time.sleep(60)
    else:
        newTags = []
        for tag in tagsOfInterest:
             if tag not in originalTags:
                  newTags.append(tag)
                  # Email newTags to myself
        originalTags = newTags
        # time.sleep(60)
```

Edit: tagsOfInterest, and the request that generates it, should be within the while loop.

Comment: Depending on what you're scraping, and depending on the page you're scraping from, there may be better options, such as talking to an API or websocket.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your help. My main concern here is if I've implemented flow control and variable definitions efficiently. This code seems very clunky to me, and I just want to make sure that there isn't a *much* easier way to do this. I spent a long time determining how to make the above code work, so I'm skeptical it's really the best.

Comment: I think this is the disadvantage of webscraping. Moreover, a slight change in the website, will break the code. That's why it is always recommended to use the official api (if exists).

Comment: For code that works fine but you want its efficiency reviewed, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi Pravnav, thanks for the info—I had never heard of Code Review before. I’ll keep that in mind for future questions.